# Overflow and css3 columns

Tags: html, css

I am unable to make a css3 column layout work with scrolls in a defined-height container area. Here is an example link:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQNeVX

All I do in css is to define this to the container area -

```
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-column-count: 4; 
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
}
```

What should I do in this case to make overflow-y work as a scroll?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set height to max-height

```
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#container {
  width: 500px;
  max-height: 200px; /* like this*/
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-column-count: 4; 
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
}
```

The second method is to do so, for Moz, Opera , IE-9 and Chrome is like this:

Updated CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container-wrapper{ 
  width: 500px;
  max-height: 200px;  
  overflow-y: scroll!important;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#container {
  -webkit-column-count: 4; 
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
}
```

Updated HTML

```
<div id="container-wrapper">
   <div id="container">

   </div>
</div>
```

Do come back if you still face any issues.

Comment: I just realized this does not work in firefox or safari

Comment: Oh.. let me check.! I  will update my answer with the modification.